# Is there a word to describe the process of making animals scared of humans again?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

As the title states, I am looking for a word that describes the method/process by which animals are made to fear humans after becoming too comfortable.

For example, bears may encroach in an area where humans are present after previously being scared. Then the humans do something to scare them enough that they once again fear humans. Maybe the opposite of habituation?

Answer (score 1):

**Dishabituation** is generally reversing the process of habituation, including the habituation of animals, but bear in mind that this is only a subset of what the word means. Habituation doesn't necessarily mean an animal getting accustomed to humans, and hence, dishabituation doesn't exclusively mean "animals getting scared of humans"

[Details on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dishabituation)